# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException error when trying to read a csv file with spark in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I am encountering the following error when I try to read a csv file with spark in my springboot app: `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.lang.String java.net.URI.scheme accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7d3a22a9`

This is the code I am trying to run

```
Dataset<Row> csvDatas = spark.read()
                                .format("csv")
                                .option("header", "true") // Assuming the CSV file has a header
                                .load(filePath);

                        // Show the DataFrame
                        csvDatas.show();
```

this is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dbtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <!--<exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>-->
                <!-- Add more exclusions if needed -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-modules=jdk.jshell
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.javap=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you see in the pom.xml file I tried to make java version and spark versions compatible and I tried adding plugins to solv the issue but it didn't work